# Authenticate mongodb on aws linux server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I know this has been asked many times before but trust me i have used that,

I just want to know the step to step procudure to authenticate the **mongodb 3.0+** on linux aws server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following procedure to enable auth on stand-alone mongodb deployment:

1. Create an administrator user

> `use admin`
>
> ```
>    db.createUser(
>       {
>         user: "userAdmin",
>         pwd: "xxxxx",
>         roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
>       }
>     )
> ```

2. Modify mongod.conf file to enable auth

> `security:
>
>   authorization: enabled`

3. Restart mongod service:

> `sudo service mongod restart`

4. Connect and authenticate as the user administrator

> `mongo 
>   use admin 
>   db.auth("userAdmin", "xxxxx")`

5. Create additional users as needed for your deployment:

> ```
> use yourdb
> db.createUser(
>   {
>     user: "testuser",
>     pwd: "xxxxxx",
>     roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "yourdb" }
>              ]
>   }
> )
> ```

6. Try logging in using mongo shell

> `mongo`

Reference [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

Comment: thanks but i cannot access it thorugh my java application it is saying [conn129] assertion 13 not authorized

Comment: What db you are authenticating against? What your code looks like?

Comment: i think i have to do some changes in my java code to autheticate from java ..very well thanks